# How to avoid duplication record?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a 'save' button to insert new record to another sheet. But I want to avoid inserting same data (a data is same if name + lastname + birthday are equals to new data). I'm trying the following code but it's too slow and not working. What are wrong with the code below ? Thanks

```
Sub saveFormData()

  Dim name As String, lastname As String, birthday As String

  ' Get last empty row
  lastRow = Sheets("saveData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  name = Worksheets("form").Range("A1").Value
  lastname = Worksheets("form").Range("A2").Value
  birthday = Worksheets("form").Range("A3").Value

  For i = 2 To lastRow

    ' Check if data exist (record is unique if we have name + lastname + birthday

    If Worksheets("saveData").Range("A" & lastRow).Value = name and Worksheets("saveData").Range("B" & lastRow).Value = lastname and Worksheets("saveData").Range("C" & lastRow).Value = birthday Then

      MsgBox "Data already exist"

      Exit Sub 'Exit from Sub

  End If
 Next

' Save name
Worksheets("saveData").Range("A" & lastRow).Value = name

' Save lastname
Worksheets("saveData").Range("B" & lastRow).Value = lastname

   ' Save birthday
   Worksheets("saveData").Range("C" & lastRow).Value = birthday

   End Sub
```

Comment: You should use the i variable instead of lastRow in your for loop, I'm trying to rebuild your code using an array to enhance the speed of you are working with thousand of items, but if not, just change the variable lastRow to i. I'll try to post code as well with an array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
Sub saveFormData()


Dim name As String, lastname As String, birthday As String

'Declare the worksheets
Dim sdSH As Worksheet, fSH As Worksheet
Set sdSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("saveData")
Set fSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("form")


' Get last empty row
lastrow = sdSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
name = fSH.Range("A1").Value
lastname = fSH.Range("A2").Value
birthday = fSH.Range("A3").Value

 'Transfer the data for 'saveData to array
Dim saveData() As String
ReDim Preserve saveData(1 To lastrow, 1 To 3) As String
For a = 1 To lastrow
  For b = 1 To 3
      saveData(a, b) = sdSH.Cells(a, b).Value
  Next b
Next a


For i = 2 To UBound(saveData)

  ' Check if data exist (record is unique if we have name + lastname + birthday

  If saveData(i, 1) = name And saveData(i, 2) = lastname And saveData(i, 3) = birthday Then

      MsgBox "Data already exist"

      Exit Sub 'Exit from Sub

  End If
Next

' Save name
sdSH.Range("A" & lastrow).Value = name

' Save lastname
sdSH.Range("B" & lastrow).Value = lastname

   ' Save birthday
sdSH.Range("C" & lastrow).Value = birthday

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, your code could be improved. You are looping to store the array when you can do it at once, then you are looping again through the array to check if the new entry exists. Using dictionaries will speed up the code way much (depending on the amount of data) check out my answer to see what I'm talking about :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working. I will take @Damian suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Working with arrays and dictionaries is always the fastest way to read large amounts of data:

```
Option Explicit
Sub saveFormData()

    Dim arrSaveData
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim SavedData As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Need Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference to work
    Dim i As Long

    'store the saved data inside the array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("saveData")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arrSaveData = .Range("A2:C" & LastRow)
    End With

    'Save every entry into the dictionary
    For i = LBound(arrSaveData) To UBound(arrSaveData)
        SavedData.Add arrSaveData(i, 1) & arrSaveData(i, 2) & arrSaveData(i, 3), 1
    Next i

    Dim name As String, lastname As String, birthday As String

    'store your variables
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("form")
        name = .Range("A1")
        lastname = .Range("A2")
        birthday = .Range("A3")
    End With

    'Check if the new entry doesn't exists and if it doesn't add it
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SaveData")
        If Not SavedData.Exists(name & lastname & birthday) Then
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, 1) = name
            .Cells(LastRow, 2) = lastname
            .Cells(LastRow, 3) = birthday
        Else
            MsgBox "Data already exists."
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

The code might not work if your `birthday`data are dates, the array will store them as dates and your `birthday`variable is a string, so in that case you should switch `birthday As Date`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will combine with @Love coding one